# At least one of minimum, optimum, or maximum IPD must be specified on table - XSL-FO Apache FOP

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am writing an XSL stylesheet for XSL-FO transfomration to create a PDF, with tables, using Apache FOP library. I have succeeded in getting PDF document with data. But having some issues with the layout. The following lines are getting printed to my Netbeans IDE console, while creating PDF.

```
[ERROR] At least one of minimum, optimum, or maximum IPD must be specified on table.
[INFO] area contents overflows area in line
```

My table cell contents are getting overlapped due to this. I want to know what IPD is and how to set it. I am a beginner in using XSL-FO and so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: IPD is short for "inline progression dimension". This seems to be a problem with missing width specifications on fo:table or fo:table-column. What version of FOP are you using?

Comment: Now I have defined column-width for all columns and the issue is solved. I still have value overlapping problem, in date column, because time also gets displayed along with date. I can handle this by formating date. FOP version used is 0.20.5. Thanks