# At least one of minimum, optimum, or maximum IPD must be specified on table

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm getting this error (Title) when trying to execute a Render using Fo.Net when creating a PDF.

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public static void MakePdf(XmlDocument xslFoDocument, Stream outputStream)
    {
        FonetDriver driver = PdfPrinterDriver.InitFonetDriver();
        driver.Render(xslFoDocument, outputStream);
    }
```

I found another post on this subject (for Java rather than for C# as I'm using but i assume it is the same error with the same cause): [At least one of minimum, optimum, or maximum IPD must be specified on table - XSL-FO Apache FOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935782/at-least-one-of-minimum-optimum-or-maximum-ipd-must-be-specified-on-table-xs). The problem is that I can't find anywhere in the xsl file below where size hasn't been set. Anyone know what might be wrong? Below is the full XSL stylesheet file

EDIT: After further Troubleshooting I managed to localize the table causing the exception to be thrown. I still can't see where I've missed declaring the size though.

```
                    <fo:table-column column-width="7cm"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$units">
                        <xsl:variable name="bgcolor">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">white</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>#F4F2F0</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <fo:table-column background-color="{$bgcolor}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <fo:table-body>

                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>

                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$units">
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="not(contains($hiddenGroups, 'image'))">
                                            <fo:block margin-top="3mm" margin-left="4mm" margin-right="4mm" margin-bottom="-0.8mm">               

                                                <fo:external-graphic content-width="500mm" width="100%" src="{$apiurl}ImageFiles/{Attributes/Attribute[@id='Image']/FileInfo/@id}/Data?apikey={$apikey}"/>                            
                                            </fo:block>
                                            <fo:block background-color="white" font-weight="600" padding-top="2mm" padding-bottom="2mm" margin-left="4mm" margin-right="4mm" margin-bottom="3mm">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>                                            
                                            <fo:block background-color="white" font-weight="600" padding-top="2mm" padding-bottom="2mm" margin-top="3mm" margin-left="4mm" margin-right="4mm" margin-bottom="3mm">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                            </fo:block>    
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-row>

                        <xsl:for-each select="$general_attributes">
                            <xsl:variable name="attribute_id" select="@id"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="attribute_type" select="@attributeDefinitionType"/>
                            <xsl:if test="not(contains(@id, 'HIDE_COMP'))">
                                <fo:table-row keep-with-previous="always" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="thin" border-bottom-color="#D0D0D0">
                                    <fo:table-cell display-align="center" padding-top="2mm" padding-bottom="2mm">
                                        <fo:block margin-left="2mm" margin-right="2mm">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>:
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$units">
                                        <fo:table-cell padding-top="2mm" padding-bottom="2mm" padding-left="4mm" padding-right="4mm" display-align="center" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-width="0.1mm" border-color="#D0D0D0">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="show-attribute">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$attribute_type"/>
                                                <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="Attributes/Attribute[@id=$attribute_id]"/>
                                                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count($units)"/>
                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                       <xsl:if test="not(contains($hiddenGroups, 'Enkät'))">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$specific_attributes">
                            <xsl:variable name="attribute_id" select="@id"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="attribute_type" select="@attributeDefinitionType"/>

                            <xsl:if test="not(@group = preceding-sibling::*/@group)">
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell padding-top="10mm" padding-bottom="5mm" number-columns-spanned="{1 + count($units)}">
                                         <fo:block font-size="13" font-weight="bold" color="white" background-color="#0191ac" padding-top="2mm" padding-bottom="1.5mm" margin-bottom="2mm"> 
                                            <fo:inline padding-left="4mm"><xsl:value-of select="@group"/></fo:inline>                                               
                                        </fo:block>                                           
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <fo:table-row keep-with-previous="always" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="thin" border-bottom-color="#D0D0D0">
                                <fo:table-cell display-align="center" padding-top="2mm" padding-bottom="2mm">
                                    <fo:block margin-left="2mm" margin-right="2mm">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <xsl:for-each select="$units">
                                    <fo:table-cell padding-top="2mm" padding-bottom="2mm" padding-left="4mm" padding-right="4mm" display-align="center" border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid" border-width="0.1mm" border-color="#D0D0D0">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="show-attribute">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$attribute_type"/>
                                            <xsl:with-param name="attribute" select="Attributes/Attribute[@id=$attribute_id]"/>
                                            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count($units)"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                       </xsl:if>

                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
```

Comment: Your `fo:table` element is missing the `width` (or `inline-progression-dimension`) attribute.

Comment: [FO.NET](http://fonet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Home) does not look like software that is actively maintained. It is based on version 0.20.4 of FOP (which is OLD).

Comment: Yeah, It's not optimal for this but it's the only one I managed to find that could actually perform this operation (only open source). It seems as if C# is not suitable at all for PDF Generation from xsl-fo. Have anyone tried using CSS2 for this instead?

Comment: @lfurini, How can I achieve dynamic width using FO.NET. I've read somewhere that the only way to do so is to declare width of the first column (the one set to 7cm in my code above). Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm marking this as answered and reference to the first comment from @lfurini. As for the last question @lfurini, I was looking at the wrong table when I thought I'd set the table width already. So to sum up for anyone else also wondering about this; If the width is set in fo:table, it's enough to set the width on one of the columns and the rest will adjust.